# new to rails : relationships not setup right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Right now I have some functionality working but its really ugly and I know there's a better way to do it.

Here's what I have right now in my User model:

```
def attending
dayseventsusers=self.days_events_users
daysevents=Array.new
events=Array.new

dayseventsusers.each do |deu| 
  daysevents<<DaysEvent.find(deu['days_events_id'])
end

daysevents.each do |de|
  events<<Event.find(de['event_id'])
end

return events
end
```

I'm trying to get a list of events for a certain group of dayseventsusers records but I have to move through several relationships to accomplish this. What I'd really like to do is something like self.days_events_users.days_event.event, but I don't know if it can be this simple assuming my relationships are setup correctly.

```
User model
has_many :days_events_users

DaysEventsUsers model
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :days_event

DaysEvent
has_many :days_events_users
belongs_to :event
```

The days_events_users object belong to a single days_event, which belongs to a single event. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having tested this, does the following work:

```
dayseventusers.collect(&:daysevent).collect(&:event)
```

Comment: It worked I ended up using: self.days_events_users.collect(&:days_event).collect(&:event). Thanks! What does the & do in this case?

Comment: IIRC the & is just a way of passing a reference to a method (in this case, :days_event and :event methods to the collection.